# How to create a new git branch and push to server with checkout full repository

Tags: git

I have many android aosp repos, i want to create a branch for each git repository in the repo and i know the commit id for the new branch,i was suggested can i create the branch without full clone the code.

```
$mkdir testgit
$cd testgit
$git init
$git remote add origin http://www.xxxx.com/test.git
$echo 08242d114ca463bd77beee424d336db0cf1ca6ae > .git/refs/heads/testbranch
$git push origin testbranch --force 
#failed
$git send-pack .git testbranch --force
#failed
```

Comment: When you say 'failed', what was the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shallow clone with `git clone --depth <depth>` where only the last `<depth>` commits of each branch are cloned or even use `--single-branch` to only clone one specific branch. See [man-page of git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for more information.